# Generic Function for Selecting Data From A Database Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Heyah,
I'm trying to create a single function that can be called from anywhere in the program where you just specify the data table.  The reason for this is so that it's easier to get data out of a table when I need to as I can just use this function.  So far, I've had no luck.

I've thrown my code below:

```
        public DataTable SELECT(Database context)
        {
            using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
            {
                var query = from i in context.Names
                            select i;

                query.CopyToDataTable(dataTable, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
                return dataTable;
            }
        }
```

I can't figure out how to pass through the required table through in the arguments.  I'm starting to wonder if this can actually be done but if anyone could lend a hand I would really appreciate it.

Comment: _"query.CopyToDataTable(dataTable, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);"_ I do **not** advise you to use DataTables here. What if the table contains 1 million rows and you only need the first row... With that, this method becomes obsolete ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I did wonder whether I should, at later stages, I hope to add other arguments to the function to allow for selecting what I actually want.  As for the data table, the only reason I used it was because that is what I'm used to using.  What would you recommend using?

Comment: I would filter the `context.Names` directly. This way the query is (most likely) executed server sided. At the moment you use FirstOrDefault() only one row is retreived.

Comment: You thinking something like this?    
var query = (from i in context.Names
                            where i.FirstName == "test"
                            select i).FirstOrDefault<Names>();

Comment: Yep: `var query = (from i in context.Names where i.FirstName == "test" select i).FirstOrDefault();`   or  `context.Names.Where(i => i.FirstName == "test").FirstOrDefault()`  or directly `context.Names.FirstOrDefault(i => i.FirstName == "test")`. There are some ways to log the query which is executed on the SQL server

Comment: I quite like the third one!  I'm a bit confused as to how you would go about getting multiple rows using this method but for single rows, it's perfect!

Comment: The DataTable is old, it would be wise to avoid it. The Names table is already returning a class which contains the columns/fields. When you've done the filtering, you could use the ToList() to persist it, but only if you need to. The ToList will load all results into the memory. If you want to export rows, you don't want to put it into a list, but use the foreach directly on the query/result

Comment: Ah I see, I think this works (assuming that this was what you meant):
`List<Names> names = query.ToList();
                foreach (Names temp in names)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(temp.FirstName);
                }`

Comment: if you foreach it ones, don't use tolist

Comment: That's fair enough.  I've got it working, thank you matey!

The other problem that I was trying to overcome with this subroutine is the ability to have this work for any datatable where you just specify the data table you want to access the data from.  Is such a thing possible?